# POST Request MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: reactjs, laravel, database

so I'm trying to implement a Watchlist for my React + Laravel App.
When clicking on a Button it should be added into a column in the DB.

I'm getting this Exception:
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException

This is my WatchlistController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class WatchlistController extends Controller
{
    public function addMovie(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
    
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'movie_ids' => 'required|integer',
            'type' => 'required|in:movie,tv',
        ]);
    
        // Add console log
        dd('addMovie function called'); // You can modify the log message as needed
    
        if ($validatedData['type'] === 'movie') {
            $user->movie_ids()->attach($validatedData['movie_ids']);
        } elseif ($validatedData['type'] === 'tv') {
            $user->tv_ids()->attach($validatedData['movie_ids']);
        }
    
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Movie/TV show added to watchlist successfully']);
    }
    
}
```

This is my routes/api.php file with the Routes:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\WatchlistController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    Route::apiResource('/users', UserController::class);
});

Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/watchlist', [WatchlistController::class, 'addMovie']);
```

And heres my Function in the Frontend:

```
const toggleLike = () => {
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);

    axiosClient.post('/watchlist', { movie_ids: `${id}`, type })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    };
```

This is my axios-client

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {useStateContext} from "./context/ContextProvider.jsx";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}/api`
})

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    return config;
})

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
})

export default axiosClient
```

Comment: Show the route for `watchlist`

Comment: `$request->validate` can sometimes perform a Redirect to the current route, which is `/watchlist`, which is a `POST` method only. Are you sending the proper AJAX headers? Check your `axiosClient` and ensure it's sending `contentType: application/JSON` in it's headers.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I posted the axios client above :) I'm pretty new to this but does it make a huge difference.

And btw i use the axios client also for the auth

Comment: Cool, so yeah, it looks like you're not setting the `Accept` and/or `Content-Type` headers. I haven't used Axios recently, but I _think_ you can add `config.headers.Accept = 'application/json';` and/or `config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`, then see if you still get the redirect.

Comment: Sorry but, i dont really know where to set that :/

Comment: As @TimLewis suggested I think you can do it in your axiosClient like 
`axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
  config.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  return config;
})`.

Comment: This is your code, right? You're already setting the `Bearer` Authorization header, I figured you would be able to look at your code, look at my comment, and figure it out... Ali's comment clarifies that, but I didn't think I was being cryptic or vague or anything 